# Data frame multiple columns splitting

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe of the following format.

```
0     06-10-2000 Deposit $40.00
1  09-12-2002 Withdraw $1000.00
2     27-06-2001 Deposit $47.00
3   07-12-2021 Withdraw $100.00
4    06-10-2022 Deposit $120.00
5     06-10-2000 Deposit $40.00
6    09-12-2024 Withdraw $50.00
```

How do I split each row in to 3 columns. 
Ideal output wanted:

```
      Date       Status   Amount
0     06-10-2000 Deposit $40.00
1  09-12-2002 Withdraw $1000.00
2     27-06-2001 Deposit $47.00
3   07-12-2021 Withdraw $100.00
4    06-10-2022 Deposit $120.00
5     06-10-2000 Deposit $40.00
6    09-12-2024 Withdraw $50.00
```

Comment: When reading your CSV use `pd.read_csv(your_file, sep='\s+', engine='python')`

Comment: `s.str.split(expand=True)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use named groups and `extract`:

```
df[1].str.extract('(?P<Date>.*) (?P<Status>.*) (?P<Amount>.*)')
```

Output:

```
         Date    Status    Amount
0  06-10-2000   Deposit    $40.00
1  09-12-2002  Withdraw  $1000.00
2  27-06-2001   Deposit    $47.00
3  07-12-2021  Withdraw   $100.00
4  06-10-2022   Deposit   $120.00
5  06-10-2000   Deposit    $40.00
6  09-12-2024  Withdraw    $50.00
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the separator in the column is a `whitespace`, you can use [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with `expand=True`:

```
df[['col1','col2','col3']] = df['column'].str.split(expand=True)
```